# Find the vectors that are perpendicular to two lines

Tags: linear-algebra, analytic-geometry

Let $y=mx+b$ and $y=m'x+c$ be the equations of two lines in the plane. Write down vectors perpendicular to these lines. Show that these vectors are perpendicular to each other if and only if $mm'=-1$

I don't know how to find these vectors. The answer key states that these two vectors are $(-m, 1)$ and $(-m', 1)$.

From this, I can easily conclude that these two vectors are perpendicular when their dot products equals zero. that means $(-m, 1) \cdot (-m', 1)=mm'+1=0,$ thus $mm'=-1$

But how do you find these vectors to begin with?

Comment: You can try to prove why $mm'=-1$ starting from a graph and using two generic straight lines. Once you are convinced that it is in fact true, apply the definition of gradient of a line and from that you can obtain your desired result.

Comment: @Fede1 I have proved it, knowing the vector, I just don't know how to find these two vectors in the first place.

Comment: **Hint** To make things easy, let's consider two lines on the plane and let's apply a translation such that they intersect at the origin. Now take two random vector along each line, say $u=(1,k_1), v=(1,k_2)$. The two lines are perpendicular if and only if $u\perp v$, $$u\cdot v=1+k_1k_2=0$$.
You should be able to finish the proof off from here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how you may find the vector $(-m,1)$.

Observe that $(0,b)$ and $(1,m+b)$ are the two points on the given line $y=mx+b$. They also represent two vectors $\vec{A}(0,b)$ and  $\vec{B}(1,m+b)$, respectively, and their difference represents a vector parallel to the line $y=mx+b$, i.e.

$$\vec{B}(1,m+b)-\vec{A}(0,b)=\vec{AB}(1,m)$$

That is, the coordinates of the vector parallel to the line is just the coefficients of $y$ and $x$ in the line equation.

Similarly, given that the line $-my=x$ is perpendicular to $y=mx+b$, the vector parallel to $-my= x$, or perpendicular to $y=mx+b$ is $\vec{AB}_{\perp}(-m,1)$.

The other vector $(-m',1)$ can be deduced likewise.

Comment: You mean $\vec{B}(1, m+b)$ instead of $(0, m+b)$?

Comment: @JamesWarthington - Correct, corresponding to $x=1$ and $y=m+b$.Thanks for the catch

Comment: @JamesWarthington - Right. Normally, it is written as $y=-\frac1m x$. It is rearranged here to be suitable for this question.

Comment: Yeah, I see that, thank you! I don't know why I even ask that.

Comment: so you can view vectors as coefficients of an equation?

Comment: @JamesWarthington - that's the trick, or linkage

Comment: what is linkage, may I ask? So you can view vectors as coefficients of an equation right?

Comment: @JamesWarthington - which is what you pointed out, view vectors as coefficients

Comment: so say the vector of $y=mx+b$ is going to be $(1, mx+b)$, the vector of $y=mx$ is going to be $(1, mx)$, is this correct?

Comment: @JamesWarthington - Just use the coefficients. i.e. the vector of $y=mx+b$ is (1,m) and the vector of $y=mx$ is the same (1,m), since they are parallel.

Comment: So what happens if I switch $-my=x$ into $y=-\frac{1}{m}x$, the vector now is $(1, -\frac{1}{m})$, which is different from $(-m, 1)$?

Comment: They are parallel, except having different magnitudes.

Comment: You are right, two vectors are parallel if $\vec{A}=x \cdot \vec{B}$. In this case, $(-m,1)=-m \cdot [(1, -\frac{1}{m})]$

Answer (score 0):

Observe that $y=mx+b$ is equivalent to $-mx+y=b$, i.e. $(-m)\cdot x+1\cdot y=b$, that is, it consists of exactly those points $p=(x,y)$, which satisfy
$$(-m, 1)\cdot p=b$$
This line is parallel to $(-m, 1)\cdot p=0$, which is the perpendicular line at the origin to vector $(-m, 1)$.

Comment: I understand the part $-mx+y=b$ part, but I don't understand how do you get $(-m,1) \cdot p=b$. Can you explain this a bit further?

Comment: I mean the dot product here: $(-m, 1)\cdot (x, y) =-mx+1\cdot y$.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a geometrically motivated explanation.

Let $(x_1,mx_1+c)$ and $(x_2,mx_2+c)$ be the coordinates of two **different** points $A$ and $B$ on the line $y=mx+c$. Consider any vector $v$ that starts at the origin, has the endpoint $(a,b)$ and is perpendicular to the same line.

Then $B-A=(x_2-x_1,m(x_2-x_1))$ should be perpendicular to $v$, i.e. $v.(B-A)=0$, or
$$(x_2-x_1)a+m(x_2-x_1)b=0
\\\implies a+mb=0\implies a=-mb$$

So any vector that starts at the origin and has as an endpoint of the form $(-mb,b)$ will be perpendicular to the given line. You could generalize this even further and say that any vector with starting point $(p_1,q_1)$ and endpoint $(p_2,q_2)$ such that $p_2-p_1=-m(q_2-q_1)$ is perpendicular to the line $y=mx+b$.