# Can you view vectors as coefficients of linear equations?

Tags: linear-algebra

[Find the vectors that are perpendicular to two lines](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3415646/find-the-vectors-that-are-perpendicular-to-two-lines/3415723?noredirect=1#comment7025213_3415723)

In this thread, a fellow user shows me that you can view vectors as coefficients of linear equation. So, for example

$y=mx+b$, then the vector is $(1, m)$.

I wonder if it is right to view vectors as coefficients of an equation. Is it true you can view it this way?

Comment: It is the direction vector, and it is a vector in the dual space.

Comment: @Bernard What is dual space, can you explain more

Comment: The dual space of a vector space $V$ is the space of linear forms on $V$, i.e. $\mathscr L(V,K)$, where $K$ is the base field.

Answer (score 0):

You describe a line in the plane by  considering a vector $X_{0} \in \mathbb{R}^{2}$ (initial point) and a direction vector $X_{1}\in \mathbb{R}^{2}$ (Draw a picture! It'll be easier to understand this). Then the line you get is the set of points $Z \in \mathbb{R}^{2}$ such that $Z = X_{0} + t X_{1}$, $t \in \mathbb{R}$, or as you did you can consider the set of all vectors $Z = (x, y)$ such that $y = mx + b$, in this case,
\begin{eqnarray}
Z & = & (x, y) \\
  & = & (x, mx+b) \\ 
  & = & (x, mx) + (0, b)\\
  & = & x(1, m) + (0, b) 
\end{eqnarray}
in other words, this equation $y = mx + b$ describes the set of all points $Z$ passing by $(0, b)$ and with direction vector $(1, m)$. This is one explanation of why this vector $(1, m)$ is related with your line.

Comment: How do you get the point $(0; b)$

Comment: By definition, if $A = (a, b)$ and $B= (c, d)$ then $A + B = (a + c, b+d)$. In this case $A = (x, xm)$ and $B = (0, b)$ and $A + B = (x, mx + b)$.

Comment: I still don't understand how do you get from $(x, mx+b)=x(1, m)+(0, b)$. Now, what is the vector that is perpendicular to y=mx+b? Can you tell me? Why is it $(-m, 1)$ and not $(-\frac{1}{m}, 1)$

Comment: I've added one more step in the prove, but take a look at this: https://www.math10.com/en/geometry/vectors-operations/vectors-operations.html for an introduction about these operations with vectors.

Comment: so you factor out $x(1, m)$? Where does x go eventually?

Comment: if you have time, can you take a look at this question: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3415646/find-the-vectors-that-are-perpendicular-to-two-lines/3415723?noredirect=1#comment7025213_3415723. I've found this website that contains relevant information, but I don't know how to find the vector that is perpendicular to $y=mx+b$ http://www.rasmus.is/uk/t/F/Su58k05.htm